# AreaDescription.SaveCurrent() freezes Unity's Update loop despite new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm developing an app with Unity and Google Tango, and part of my code is saving an Area Description File (ADF) in a separate thread (so that my UI remains responsive):

```
Debug.Log("create thread");
m_saveThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    // Start saving process in another thread.
    Debug.Log("Starting work in thread");
    currentAreaDescription = AreaDescription.SaveCurrent();
    Debug.Log("SaveCurrent completed");
    AreaDescription.Metadata metadata = currentAreaDescription.GetMetadata();
    metadata.m_name = name;
    currentAreaDescription.SaveMetadata(metadata);
});

Debug.Log("Start thread");
m_saveThread.Start();
Debug.Log("thread started");
```

My problem is that even tho I run the saving code in a new thread, the UI is still being frozen until `AreaDescription.SaveCurrent()` completes. To confirm this, I have added the following print call to my `Update()`:

```
public void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("Update!");
    //...
}
```

And this is an excerpt from `adb logcat -s Unity` at the time I save:

```
08-23 15:11:43.746 18474 18518 I Unity   : Update!
08-23 15:11:43.747 18474 18518 I Unity   : Save confirmed!
08-23 15:11:43.747 18474 18518 I Unity   : overlay
08-23 15:11:43.747 18474 18518 I Unity   : create thread
08-23 15:11:43.748 18474 18518 I Unity   : Start thread
08-23 15:11:43.753 18474 18518 I Unity   : thread started
08-23 15:11:43.754 18474 18836 I Unity   : Starting work in thread
08-23 15:11:44.960 18474 18518 I Unity   : Update!
08-23 15:11:44.961 18474 18518 I Unity   : Currently saving!
08-23 15:11:44.964 18474 18836 I Unity   : SaveCurrent completed
08-23 15:11:44.977 18474 18518 I Unity   : Update!
```

(Several irrelevant lines removed)

As can be seen by the timestamps, for the whole ~200ms that `SaveCurrent()` runs, `Update()` is not being called.

Why is the main thread being frozen despite me running this heavy function in a new thread? And what can I do to make it *actually* run in the background?

By the way, this code is almost directly adapted from [Google's own sample repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity) and I have created [an issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/issues/106) about it, currently without response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding the [C API function that gets called under the hood](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/group/area-description#group___area_description_1ga07c6db409a2be634a38ae0456236e61a) and reading its docs, I found out that

> Since the Tango Service locks internally, other API calls (such as TangoService_getPoseAtTime()) will block while this method is running.

Indeed, I have other objects in my scene that use the Tango API in their `Update()` functions, and after writing code to disable them for the time of saving, Unity does not freeze anymore.

I just wish they would have mentioned it in the [Tango docs about the Unity function I was using](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/class/tango/area-description#class_tango_1_1_area_description_1a54dcc097d871335f4ab6378ba207f2ff).

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, `SaveCurrent()` uses a **System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer** which is, according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), threadsafe.

But they initialize it with a [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where non-static members are not threadsafe.

But there is [TextWriter.Synchronized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which can help you.

Still not obvious why a separate thread would cause Unity to freeze. We have to assume that Unity waits for the thread to finish/not block anymore.

You can try to **not** extend Monobehaviour, see if Unity stops waiting then.

If that does not help, you need to read about volatile, and maybe check this relevant [answers.unity3d thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1234927/multithreading-freezes-editor.html)